# How to change max_allowed_packet parameter in MySQL database working on Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, configuration, parameters, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

First I changed this value in parameter group, which is used for my database instance

`rds-modify-db-parameter-group  <name_of_parameter_group> --parameters "name=max_allowed_packet, value=33554432, method=immediate"`

Then I checked that I successfully changed it:

`rds-describe-db-parameters <name_of_parameter_group>`

I received:

`DBPARAMETER  max_allowed_packet                   33554432                                 user            integer  dynamic  true`

Looks good, so finally I restarted this database instance, and after that I checked if it changed in mysql.
So I connected to database via mysql and checked variables:

`> show variables`

`| max_allowed_packet                                | 1048576`

Nothing changed...

I also tried to change it from mysql, but root doesn't have SUPER privileges to do it.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: If you can restart database instance, you should have the super privileges, or I get it wrong?

Comment: I can restart it using rds-reboot-db-instance command. But I don't know how to get SUPER privileges. I read that on amazon-rds it is impossible.

Comment: I found solution. It was my mistake, I wanted to do everything in eu-west-1 region, but I had parameter_group in us region which has the same name, and I did almost everything for it. Sorry...